# How to create a dictionary out of four lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, beautifulsoup

This is my first question in SO and I am new to python (and to Beautifulsoup) so I hope I'm clear enough.

I have four functions outputting four lists stored in four variables (inst, degree, major, dates).

I'm trying to build a dictionary with "inst" as the key and the other three variables as values.

I have tried the following solution (among others):

```
data = [inst, degree, major, dates] #converting lists into a matrix
```

and then re-arranging the items with:

```
print dict((x[0], (x[1], x[2], x[3])) for x in data[1:])
```

But I'm getting an `"IndexError: list index out of range"`

How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_dict = {x : [y, z, t] for x,y,z,t in zip(inst, degree, major, dates)}
```

Comment: I noticed that when there is any value missing, my_dict will not output the key:value pair. Is there a way to handle this (i.e.: print the pair with "None")? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by missing value? The lists inst, degree major and dates all have the same length, right? If you have only one None in inst, it should appear in they keys (just try `my_dict[None]`)... if there are several... the first entry will be overwritten with the second and so on...  but I guess I don't understand exactly what you mean

Comment: etna, thanks for answering. degree has one less value than the other variables (and this could happen all time with any of the variables). For this reason the my_dict output totaly excludes the key:value pair (that should have three values in total, has actually two) from the list. I would like to be able to include the pair at least using: (inst, None, major, dates). I hope I make it clear enough this time. Thanks again.

Comment: If you don't know for which element of inst the value of degree is missing, I'm afraid not much can be done "at this stage". Since you mentioned BeautifulSoup, I guess that you need to fix the parsing i.e. store a None in degree when the value is missing (and the same with each field by the way).

Comment: You are right about the stage for fixing this. The original question is answered in great manner. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate to ask (maybe in a new question) if you have troubles with the parsing step